# Angular event on property change happening out of order

Tags: javascript, css, events, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Background:
I have a hint box that shows up on focus that changes size as error/info messages change.  For example, on blur the box will remain but add error message if validation of the field fails.  Then when the user starts typing the error messgae goes away. All this behavior is controlled with ng-show.  For example the error message is in a div where ng-show="hasError".  Thus when the controller set's hasError to true, the box displays the error, which in turn changes the height of the hint box.

Goal: 
I want to dynamically recenter (vertically) the box depending on offset height of the box. I due this by resetting the margin-bottom on the element.

**Problem**: 
Because the height essentially changes due to angular's directive ng-show, I'm having a hard time recalculation the tip box height at the right time, in a good way.

I can add a handler such as, handleError, which is called when an error is detected. It looks like this:

```
scope.handleError = function () {
    scope.hasError = true;
    $timeout(resetHeight, 30); 
};
```

Without the timeout code, however, the resize happens BEFORE the error is added, messing up the margin-bottom value.  I don't really feel comfortable using a timeout like this as it feels hacky and would fail if the user really does experience some slow down.

I also tried using $watch like so:

```
scope.$watch('hasError', resetHeight, true);
```

This also seems to fire BEFORE the error is shown again, messing up the margin-bottom resulting in off center display.

So the question is, in Angular,is there a way to cause some logic to execute AFTER a directive, specifically ng-show? Can a specific usage somehow be tied into much like $watch?

Thanks,

Comment: I updated my answer with what I think is the best solution and a demo to get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do lots of things, but I think making your own directive would be the most concise and effective choice. Here's an example:

```
app.directive('showResize', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.hide();
      var height = 50;
      scope.$watch(attrs.showResize, function(shouldShow) {
        if (shouldShow) {
          console.log('ran');
          element.show(); 
          height = height+50;
          console.log(height);
          element.css('height', height+'px');       
        }
        else { element.hide(); }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

This gives you control over the order that things show/hide and resize, so you don't need `ng-show` at all.

[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/AkanEH/11/edit)

Comment: Thanks @m59. So judging by your answer, the answer to my question is no, there's no way to tie into directives in some way.  If an included directive doesn't work (do everything you need) you have to write a custome one.  There's no extending them persay...

Comment: @Ironosity Well, that's mostly correct. Angular is so flexible and powerful that you *could* make `ng-show` do what you want, but it would be an awful idea. I don't know if you saw my original answer, but I discussed some options that almost become hack like. Between creating wrapper directives (that would apply another angular directive), the directive priority attribute, promises, `$watch` and events, you can do all kinds of crazy things. I just think simply writing your own directive would be much more effective. Much more. `ng-show` is only a few lines anyway!